# pd.read_excel() bug for single level MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Consider the following MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

I = range(2)
C = range(2)

mi_i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I], names=['i'])
mi_c = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([C], names=['c'])

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=mi_i, columns=mi_c)

df.to_excel('df.xlsx')

df_in = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx', index_col=0, header=0)
```

Printing `df`  yields

```
c  0  1
i      
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

The xlsx Output is correct

[image: table]

After reading the xlsx and printing the DataFrame `df_in` the following, erroneous table occurs

```
     0    1
c    
i  NaN  NaN    
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't this it's really bug, more of a non implemented feature. This is the same if you export to text and try to import again. The ambiguity is that it's difficult to know whether this second row is a column level or index name.

Comment: But the same ambiguity problem would arise for more than one column level. However, it works perfectly fine if I had two columns levels. I think it's a bug in the sense that there is an inconsistent beahivor for single-leveled multiindex columns and "real" multiindices.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_in = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx', header=[0])
df_in.set_index("c",inplace = True)
df_in = df_in.rename_axis(None,axis=0).rename_axis('c',axis=1)
```

Try this

It worked here, you can use the [.rename_axix()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to fix your header.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).